Filter SetupAuditTrail query
The below query pulls in the records. I want to filter them to only see where an administrator logged in as another user.
List<SetupAuditTrail> auditTrailList = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Username,  Display, Section, DelegateUser
                                          FROM SetupAuditTrail
                                          WHERE CreatedDate >=: startDate AND CreatedDate < : endDate
                                          ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];

List<SetupAuditTrail> UsersauditTrailList = new List <SetupAuditTrail>();

The below works:
for (SetupAuditTrail allaud: auditTrailList) {
    if (allaud.section == 'Manage Users' )
        UsersauditTrailList.add(allaud);
}

But I can't get any filter on Action LIKE 'Logged'.
I want to return only where SetupAuditTrail Action starts with 'Logged'.

Maybe something like this should work:
SELECT Action, Display FROM SetupAuditTrail WHERE Action LIKE 'suOrgAdmin%' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC

Looks like you're in Apex, so filtering by System Admin profile shouldn't be an issue using DelegateUser field on SetupAuditTrail.

AND Action LIKE 'Logged%' to the query returns no rows in the class. When I try it in the query editor I get: field 'Section' can not be filtered in a query call

What do you get when you use Action LIKE 'suOrgAdmin%'?

same - Section cannot be filtered in a query call- I need to filter in the later for loop I guess

Use only Action LIKE 'suOrgAdmin%' without the Section field in the filters. That should give you the list of records you want.

that worked - can you explain it a little more?

I couldn't find anything in Salesforce Documentation about 'suOrgAdmin...'. I simply queried all rows for SetupAuditTrail in my sandbox (very few records) and it was straight forward that these 'suOrgAdmin..' Action rows meant what you were looking for.
